# discontinuity for $h(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}}(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{|x|}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}})$ for $x\neq0$ $h(x)=\frac{1}{2}$ for $x=0$

Tags: calculus

Consider $h:R→R$ with $h(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}}(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{|x|}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}})$ for $x\neq0$

$h(x)=\frac{1}{2}$ for $x=0$

i think there is a discontinuity at $x=\frac{1}{2}$ but i do not know how to show it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is continuous. Do you know L'hopital rule?

Answer (score 1):

We only need to check the continuity at $x=0$.

We have
\begin{align} \lim_{x\to0^\pm}\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}}\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{|x|}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}}\right) &= \lim_{x\to0^\pm}\frac{1}{|x|}\left(\sqrt{|x|+1}-1\right) \\
&= \lim_{x\to0^\pm}\frac{1}{|x|}\left(1+\frac{|x|}{2}+O(|x|^2)-1\right) \\
&= \lim_{x\to0^\pm}\frac{1}{|x|}\left(\frac{|x|}{2}+O(|x|^2)\right) \\
&=\frac{1}{2}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Since the function is even, that is, $h(-x)=h(x)$, we just need to compute
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}h(x)
$$
because this will be necessarily equal to the limit from the right. So we have
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\Bigl(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\Bigr)
=
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{\sqrt{x+1}-1}{x}=
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{x+1-1}{x(\sqrt{x+1}+1)}=\frac{1}{2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $y= 1/\sqrt{|x|}$ then 
$h=y(\sqrt{1+y^2}-y)$.

Using $\sqrt{a}-b=(a-b^2)/(\sqrt{a}+b)$ as in $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$ we get:

$h=y\frac{1+y^2-y^2}{\sqrt{1+y^2}+y}=
\frac{y}{y (\sqrt{1/y^2+1}+1)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1/y^2+1}+1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|+1}+1}\to \frac{1}{2}$ as $x\to 0$.